# crontab not working: perhaps an error in notation?

Tags: unix, amazon-ec2, shiny, cron

In an Amazon EC2 terminal, I type: `sudo nano crontab -e' to bring up the editor. I have the following (empty line at the end included):

```
@reboot echo "Running RMV scrape & R Shiny via: nano crontab -e"
@reboot nohup python /home/ec2-user/RMV/RMV_scrape.py &
@reboot nohup shiny-server &
@reboot service start httpd
@hourly cp -f /home/ec2-user/RMV/wait_times.csv /var/shiny-server/www/wait_times.csv
```

Here, I'm trying to run (a) my program, (b) apache, (c) R Shiny server and (d) a script that runs hourly to copy a file.

For some reason, this fails to run. `pgrep chron` does show `chron` runs upon startup. It shouldn't be a permissions issue because I ran `crontab` using `sudo`. I had one relative pathname in my `.py` script but I changed it to an absolute pathname.

I've consulted:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/23009/reasons-why-crontab-does-not-work
- http://www.unix.com/answers-to-frequently-asked-questions/13527-cron-crontab.html

Any ideas why this may not be working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problems is with the command you used to edit the crontab `sudo nano crontab -e` does not edit the crontab you made a file named crontab in whatever directory you were working in, but crontab files are in /var and are not intended to be edited directly. For any given user `crontab -e` will edit the crontab using the editor specified in the environment variable EDITOR. So to edit root's crontab the command is `sudo crontab -e`.

That said adding entries to root's crontab is probably not what you want. You probably want to use the system crontab for some thing like this. In almost all cases the system crontab is `/etc/crontab` which can be edited using `sudo nano /etc/crontab`. Note that for the system crontab you need to add the user of the command between the time and command sections. e.g.

```
@reboot root echo "Running RMV scrape & R Shiny via: nano crontab -e"
```

Also note that crontab uses a very minimal PATH environment variable for security reasons. If a command you issue is not on the path it will not execute. Remember to either add the paths you need to the crontab PATH (specified in the particular crontab file) or use the full path to a given executable from the (filesystem) root directory.